# My JSP returns a 202 (SC_ACCEPTED) status, but the caller gets a 200 (SC_OK) status

Tags: java, jsp, http, tomcat, http-response-codes

I am accessing a simple JSP page on Tomcat:

```
<%@ page import = "java.io.Writer" %>
<%
try {
    Writer outWriter = response.getWriter ();
    outWriter.write ("something");
    outWriter.flush ();
    response.setStatus (HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
}
catch (Throwable t) {
  response.sendError (HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, t.getMessage ());
}%>
```

But when I test this page with `curl`, I get a 200 response code instead of the expected 202:

```
$ curl -i "http://localhost:8090/somepath/somefile.jsp"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=52......................AD2; Path=/somepath/; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 05 Jun 2017 08:09:36 GMT

something
```

If I remove the content from the response:

```
<%@ page import = "java.io.Writer" %>
<%
try {
    //Writer outWriter = response.getWriter ();
    //outWriter.write ("something");
    //outWriter.flush ();
    response.setStatus (HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
}
catch (Throwable t) {
  response.sendError (HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, t.getMessage ());
}%>
```

I get the desired response code:

```
$ curl -i "http://localhost:8090/somepath/somefile.jsp"
HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=52......................AD2; Path=/somepath/; HttpOnly
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Length: 2
Date: Mon, 05 Jun 2017 08:12:57 GMT
```

Is there some Tomcat configuration changing the response code?

My actual goal is to simulate responses of some 3rd party web API that is expected to return a 202 response code + some short content string for successful requests.

My server, which would call this API, expects a 202 response. I guess I can change it to accept both 200 and 202 responses, but I wanted my code to match the documentation of the 3rd party API.

Comment: Try move the setStatus() above the 3 lines...chance are the setStatus has been overriden or ignored.

Comment: @MinhKieu This actually worked, thanks! You can post this as an answer. Any idea why the status was overriden/ignored?

Comment: I think the flush() may have set the status to 200. Once its set it cannot be override. All the examples I saw where status is set at the very beginning. The best way to confirm this is to look at the compiled java class for this. Nice one, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the setStatus() to the top of the JSP. Look at the compiled JSP to see how the code is written by the compiler. Chances are once Status has been set, it cannot be overridden. The flush() method maybe have set the Status to 200.

Comment: The compiled class looks like the original code, so that didn't help in understanding the cause. However, I found in the doc of `ServletResponse.getWriter()` that `Calling flush() on the PrintWriter commits the response`, which may mean that the response cannot be altered in any way after calling `flush()`.